# Fitness and ability to do sign language

Tags: arms, neck, hands, forearm

I have downloaded some apps illustrating sign language from the Android play store, but I have something remotely related to muscular dystrophy.

Is fitness of the arms and hands and face muscles a prerequisite for doing sign language? What if one cannot due to fatigue, sickle cell anemia, or ano other drug-induced or other tiredness condition?

Thanks.

(Also, why are the [face] and [mouth] tags missing from the list of tag choices)?

Comment: I have known people with muscular issues who have been able to sign. Much as with speech, it basically involves some degree of the person receiving the communication accounting for slurring and altered phonemes / signs. That said, this site is a bit more about exercise fitness.

Comment: Hmmm... not sure that is the case; sign language involves a !lot! of arm movement. Is there a sign language for tired people, that others can get understand?

Comment: You could always sign smaller. While typical sign ranges across the body, the same sign done in a smaller area can also be intelligible. And you're likely to be much more terse as a result.